# Laplace transformation of a piecewise function?

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

So I know in general how to do the laplace transformation of piecewise functions, but I ran into a different kind of piecewise than I have been doing so far.

So I know for a function like:

[image]

I just need to do this:

[image]

But what am I supposed to do for a piecewise function like this?:

[image]

I just want to know how to write out the second piecewise question just like the first one, I know how to do the steps after. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty=\int_0^2+\int_2^2+\int_2^\infty$$

Comment: do I not need to do anything about negative infinity to 0?

Comment: That depends - are you using the [bilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sided_Laplace_transform) definition of the transform?